# Obtener hostname y puerto del servidor

Tags: java, aplicación-web

Tengo una aplicacion web que envia correos con un link para el acceso a un modulo de mi aplicacion, pero lo he estado haciendo de manera fija con la direccion ip y puerto ya establecidos. Ahora mi aplicacion se va a subir a produccion, y el area de correos me comenta que mi aplicacion se va a montar en cluster, por lo que debo obtener estos dos parametros de forma dinamica, sin importar donde se ejecuta 
¿como lo hago?

Answer (score 1):

Hola puedes usar ServletRequest:.

```
ServletRequest.getLocalName() returns hostname.
ServletRequest.getLocalAddr() returns IP.
ServletRequest.getLocalPort() returns puerto.
```

[Interface ServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocalName%28%29)

Comment: Hay manera de hacerlo sin servletrequest??, es que los modulos de correos son ajenos al servlet

Comment: Tendrías que esplicar un poco más sobre tu código como lo tienes implementado para poder acoplar  un servlet o un getPort de la clase Socket.